# Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server... Data Source server name property changes to a dot(.) after saving solution

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, connection, datasource

We are using SQL Server 2012 Express Advanced Edition with Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

In the Server Explorer we created a connection to a SQL Server .mdf file. We set the Server Name to:

```
OURSERVER\SQLEXPRESS
```

and attached the .mdf file. Next I clicked the Test Connection button to ensure everything was working ok. I clicked the OK button thinking everything was ok and clicked the Save All icon. I also looked at the data in the database using the Server Explorer to make sure our app will be able to access it. I exited VS2010.

Later I started up VS2010 and noticed that the database needed to be connected so I click the icon to connect to the database thinking it would start up right away but it did not. Instead we saw a message stating:

```
Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server...
```

We found out through some investigation that VS2010 was trying to use a different Data Source:

```
.\SQLEXPRESS
```

Our Server Name had disappeared to a dot(.) so we tried modify the Data Source property in the Advanced Properties dialog window but this particular property was locked so typing anything in there will not be accepted. Also the only choice in the dropdown was .\SQLEXPRESS and not our Server Name.

All help to aid us in locating this dot(.) and replace it with our Server Name and to stop the dot(.) from appearing will greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution Found:

The dot(.) was found by following these steps:

- Right-click the project name in the Solution Explorer.
- Click on Properties from the pop-up menu
- Click on the Settings tab on the left side of the window that has opened.
- Locate a row in the Type column that has a ConnectionString with a Scope of Application.
- Click in the Value column of that row and change the Data Source.

After changing the Data Source by removing the dot(.) and replacing it with our server name, the issue went away.

Hopefully this will help someone facing the same issue as we did.